# Inject CSS after class added

Tags: jquery, css

I'm doing a form validation via PHP and JS and i'm trying to change icon color as shown here:

[image: example]

After submit button is clicked,I send "email" data to be validated in server. After that, the client receives value **1** for validated and **0** for not validated.

If input is valid, border color will change to green and icon color too.
If input is invalid, border color will change to red and same for the icon.

Here is the code:

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.red').css('color',"red");
           $('.green').css('color',"green");
       });
    </script>

    if(email==1){
       $("#email").css("border","1px solid red");
       $("#icon-email").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"); 
       $("#icon-email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove"); 
       $("#icon-email").addClass("red"); 
    }
    else{
       $("#email").css("border","1px solid green"); 
       $("#icon-email").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"); 
       $("#icon-email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok"); 
       $("#icon-email").addClass("green"); 
       $("#email").val(cookie_email);
   }
```

The problem is i can't change icon color but I can change border color.
I've tried to put jquery after and before class creation, but no success.
Any sugestions?

Comment: you can't add css classes/rules into the stylesheet dynamically like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `red` and `green` classes in a CSS file:

```
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem.
First i need to define css before adding a class.

```
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }



if(email==1){
   $("#email").css("border","1px solid red");
   $("#icon-email").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"); 
   $("#icon-email").addClass("red");
   $("#icon-email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove"); 

 }
 else{
   $("#email").css("border","1px solid green"); 
   $("#icon-email").removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"); 
   $("#icon-email").addClass("green");
   $("#icon-email").addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
   $("#email").val(cookie_email);
}
```